# How to implement generics over all types capable of arithmetic operations?

Tags: generics, rust

The `Number` wrapper presents subtraction on its contained type if possible. The `Difference` struct saves two numbers and their difference ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f0b0b536376c7ac35db01c206dcfeeea)):

```
use std::ops::Sub;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Number<T>(T); // Doesn't have the Copy marker
// Implements subtraction whenever the contained type does
// Only the case with references implemented for brevity
impl<'a, 'b, T> Sub<&'b Number<T>> for &'a Number<T>
where
    &'a T: Sub<&'b T, Output = T> 
{
    type Output = Number<T>;
    
    fn sub(self, rhs: &'b Number<T>) -> Number<T> {
        Number(&self.0 - &rhs.0)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Difference<T> {
    a: Number<T>,
    b: Number<T>,
    diff: Number<T>,
}
impl<'a, 'b, T: 'b + 'a> Difference<T>
where
    // "Any type for which `Number` implements subtraction"
    &'a Number<T>: Sub<&'b Number<T>, Output = Number<T>>,
{
    fn new(a: Number<T>, b: Number<T>) -> Self {
        let diff = &b - &a;
        Difference { a, b, diff }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Difference::new(Number(3), Number(5)));
}
```

This code doesn't compile for several reasons. Firstly, there's recursion while evaluating the `Sub` trait bound:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `&BTreeSet<_>: Sub<&BTreeSet<_>>`
  --> src/main.rs:36:22
   |
36 |     println!("{:?}", Difference::new(Number(3), Number(5)));
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="256"]` attribute to your crate (`playground`)
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Sub<&Number<BTreeSet<_>>>` for `&Number<BTreeSet<_>>`
  --> src/main.rs:7:17
   |
7  | impl<'a, 'b, T> Sub<&'b Number<T>> for &'a Number<T>
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: 127 redundant requirements hidden
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Sub` for `&Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<Number<BTreeSet<_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`
```

I don't understand that, because as I see it, the compiler should:

- see that `Difference::new()` is invoked
- extract the `T` type from its parameters (`{integer}` in this case)
- check if there is any valid implementation for the bounds of this type:

  ```
  `&'a Number<{integer}>: Sub<&'b Number<{integer}>, Output = Number<{integer}>>`
  ```
- see that `impl<'a, 'b, T> Sub<&'b Number<T>> for &'a Number<T>` with `type Output = Number<T>;` is the correct implementation if the bounds on `T` are satisfied
- see that every `{integer}` satisfies the `&'a T: Sub<&'b T, Output = T>` bound

It seems to me, that the compiler instead tries to recursively substitute `Number<T>` as `T`, but I don't understand why.

Even after this problem is resolved (or hidden by commenting the `println!` invocation) a new error is generated:

```
error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:30:20
   |
24 | impl<'a, 'b, T: 'b + 'a> Difference<T>
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
30 |         let diff = &b - &a;
   |                    ^^
   |                    |
   |                    borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                    requires that `b` is borrowed for `'a`
31 |         Difference { a, b, diff }
32 |     }
   |     - `b` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:30:25
   |
24 | impl<'a, 'b, T: 'b + 'a> Difference<T>
   |          -- lifetime `'b` defined here
...
30 |         let diff = &b - &a;
   |                         ^^
   |                         |
   |                         borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                         requires that `a` is borrowed for `'b`
31 |         Difference { a, b, diff }
32 |     }
   |     - `a` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `a` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:31:22
   |
24 | impl<'a, 'b, T: 'b + 'a> Difference<T>
   |          -- lifetime `'b` defined here
...
30 |         let diff = &b - &a;
   |                         --
   |                         |
   |                         borrow of `a` occurs here
   |                         requires that `a` is borrowed for `'b`
31 |         Difference { a, b, diff }
   |                      ^ move out of `a` occurs here

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `b` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:31:25
   |
24 | impl<'a, 'b, T: 'b + 'a> Difference<T>
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
30 |         let diff = &b - &a;
   |                    --
   |                    |
   |                    borrow of `b` occurs here
   |                    requires that `b` is borrowed for `'a`
31 |         Difference { a, b, diff }
   |                         ^ move out of `b` occurs here
```

The idea is that I borrow `a` and `b` for the subtraction and then give them back, so that they can be moved into the returned struct. However, in the bound `&'a Number<T>: Sub<&'b Number<T>, Output = Number<T>>` I promise that they will be borrowed for the entire duration of the function. I don't want to promise that, but I need some lifetime to be even able to specify the bound, and I don't know how to specify a shorter lifetime.

How would I go about solving these problems?

Comment: I've got to admit, the mention of BTreeSet in the error message is not exactly helpful.

Comment: As these are two different problems (first the infinite recursion, second the "`'b`does not live long enough" error), I suggest splitting this up in two questions.

Comment: Originally I only had the lifetime problem, but while trying to simplify the code for this question, I stumbled upon the recursion problem, so it is hard for me to express the lifetime one without the recursion one. Likewise, I'm so far unable to isolate the recursion problem. For example, this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5e047b575b297cf02608e2f7e9a59786 doesn't work (or rather it does), so it seems the references (and thus lifetimes) are somehow important for reproducibility. I'll try to split the questions, but I'm not sure if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all lets fix that annoying recursive type by specifying the exact type to use

```
println!("{:?}", Difference::<i32>::new(Number(3), Number(5)));
```

There type seems to be ambiguous!! (because {integer} isn't a concrete type) To be honest I don't know exactly why it goes though that recursion but it does.

Next the trait bound for ambiguous with how trait bound were you were specifying that `&'a Number<T> - &'b Number<T> = &'a+b Number<T>` witch isn't the case since you implemented that  `&'a Number<T> - &'b Number<T> = Number<T>`. To fix this I used [HRTBs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html). (To be honest you could probably do it without them but it gets annoying when there are a lot of lifetimes)

```
for<'a, 'b> &'a Number<T>: Sub<&'b Number<T>, Output = Number<T>>,
```

Full code

```
use std::ops::Sub;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Number<T>(T);

impl<'a, 'b, T> Sub<&'b Number<T>> for &'a Number<T>
where
    &'a T: Sub<&'b T, Output = T> 
{
    type Output = Number<T>;
    
    fn sub(self, rhs: &'b Number<T>) -> Number<T> {
        Number(&self.0 - &rhs.0)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Difference<T> {
    a: Number<T>,
    b: Number<T>,
    diff: Number<T>,
}
impl<T> Difference<T>
where
    // Used [HRTBs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) to define that &a - &b = c works used a single lifetime
    for<'a, 'b> &'a Number<T>: Sub<&'b Number<T>, Output = Number<T>>,
{
    fn new(a: Number<T>, b: Number<T>) -> Self {
        let diff = &b - &a;
        Difference { a, b, diff }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Defined the type because there are some recursive issues
    // Somehow the type is ambiguous!!! But the error doesn't explain anything
    // It is trying to figure out the type but when exploring all the types it throws a to many recursions error
    println!("{:?}", Difference::<i32>::new(Number(3), Number(5)));
}
```

EDIT: I just found out that this is really similar to [std::num::Wrapping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.Wrapping.html)